# Electron-electron interaction in solids

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter

We always consider a Coulomb interactions between electrons in the Hamiltonian to modelize a solid. Why not to take into account retardation effects of the electromagnetic interaction which go beyond the static Coulomb interaction? Because the electronic velocity is usually quite small compare with c?